# Darle un brackground color a una seccion del Progress bar

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy haciendo uso de un progress bar como velocimetro para que me muestre la velocidad GPS del dispositivo android, para ello, he creado un Drawable Resource File de nombre circle.xml de la sgte forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        >
        <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="12"
            android:useLevel="false"
            >
            <solid android:color="@color/securitas"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="13"
            android:useLevel="false"
            >
            <solid android:color="#ED8A8A"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="270"
            android:toDegrees="270"
            >
            <shape
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thicknessRatio="13"
                android:useLevel="true"
                >
                <solid android:color="#cb6262"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

El resultado que obtengo con el código descrito linea arriba es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito saber es cómo puedo pintar de color blanco solo la circunferencia interna, de tal forma que el resultado final me quede así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas crear varios anillos ("ring"), incluso me parece que el item final no es necesario. Te sugiero mejor usar "oval" para crear un circulo y agregar un anillo de color rojo.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/> <!-- Color blanco -->
            <stroke android:color="#ED8A8A" android:width="5dp"/>  <!-- anillo rojo -->
            <size android:width="60dp" android:height="60dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Esto tendrá como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]